# face changes as if he has seen this before?

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. John's face changes as if he has seen this before.

Here this could any thing (an object, a map, a place, a movie, etc).

Normally when you see something and if you feel as if you have seen this before, your facial expression changes reflecting that. I wrote the above sentence to describe it.  Is it grammatically correct?

I checked google, I see many sentence for "as if he has seen this before" but I don't see any sentences matching "[face changes as if * has seen this before](https://www.google.com/search?q=face%20changes%20as%20if%20he%20has%20seen%20this%20before.&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS524US524&oq=face%20changes%20as%20if%20he%20has%20seen%20this%20before.&aqs=chrome.0.69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&ei=Xx8DUvSzMKqBygHFzoHoAQ&fp=d3a358ff018da6fb&q=%22face%20changes%20as%20if%20%2a%20has%20seen%20this%20before%22&sa=X&tbm=bks&ved=0CAwQ_AUoAg)" I feel like this is valid sentence and conveys the meaning. But I'm confused since there is no match in the google. That means this sentence is wrong? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> John's face changes as if he has seen this before.

Yes, this is grammatically correct, or at least it is something that a native speaker might say. However, it would be more common in writing, but perhaps old-fashioned, to use a [pluperfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect) here:

> John's face changes as if he had seen this before.

This is an instance of a [past subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive). To reduce confusion, consider a similar sentence where the action in the conditional clause does not take place in the past:

> John's face changes as if he was not seeing this for the first time.

The use of a past subjunctive normally expresses a counterfactual statement. It is used here even though it is likely that the statement is true, because “as if” tends to call for a counterfactual statement.

If you want to express a visible change of expression and state without ambiguity that John has seen this before, and John's response is positive, you can say

> John's face lights up in recognition.

If John's reaction is negative, you might say

> John frowns in recognition.

Comment: I don't think this is right. You wouldn't normally mix present tense *changes* with past perfect *had seen*. The thing is native speakers would rarely use present tense *at all* here except as a "literary device". In most *spoken* contexts it would be *changed + **had** seen*. But in a literary context (or sometimes informal speech using present tense to describe events in the past) it would be *changes as if he's seen it before*, where *he's = he **has***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now it's gets more interesting. Now I don't know whether to use has or had. Google ngram result doesn't show any match for has but I could only search partial sentence. Here is google ngram result  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+if+he+has+seen%2Cas+if+he+had+seen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @T2E The ngram was a mistake: “as if he was seen” is overwhelmed by occurrences where the main clause is in a past tense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm surprised: you wouldn't use a subjunctive past here at all?

Comment: @ Gilles: To be honest, present tense is so unusual compared to past tense for OP's context that I'm not completely sure (["looks as if he had seen"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22looks+as+if+he+had+seen%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) : 10 hits in Google Books, [**looked** as if he had seen](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22looked+as+if+he+had+seen%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) : 168,000 hits). Plus 7 for *looks as if he **has** seen*. But the more "natural" *you look as if **you've** seen* only just edges out *you look as if **you'd** seen*, so it obviously ***is*** used